# VHDL - using PORT MAP in CASE?

Tags: vhdl

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity ALU is
Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       S : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       R : in  STD_LOGIC;
       load : in  STD_LOGIC;
       clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
       flags : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
       result : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));

end ALU;

architecture Behavioral of ALU is

signal result1 : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal c,z : STD_LOGIC;


component topleveladd

Port (
x : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
y : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
sum : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
cout : out  STD_LOGIC);

end component;

begin

stage5 : topleveladd port map(x=>A, y=>B, cin=>c, sum=>result, cout=>z);

end Behavioral;
```

I am trying to make an ALU. My plan is to make all of the neccessay circuits like the adder and the subtractor in different modules. Then I will implement them in the main ALU module using port map. My issue, is that I I don't know how to use port maps for case statements or something similar to that. For example,

```
Case S is
when "0000" =>
result <= stage5 : topleveladd port map(x=>A, y=>B, cin=>c, sum=>result, cout=>z);
```

I understand this will not work because stage5 isn't a vector.

In conclusion, I am running a port map and I want the "results" of that port map to be displayed when a certain pin is select via S. Hopefully, I provided the proper information. I am sorry if my logic doesn't add up, as I have only very few experiences with VHDL.

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate each part of the ALU separately ADD, SUB, AND, OR... with different output vectors `sum=>result_add`, `sub=>result_sub`, etc. then multiplex the outputs, either in a process with a `CASE` statement, or outside using `WHEN` and `ELSE` :

```
result<=result_add WHEN S="0000"
        ELSE result_sub WHEN S="0001"
        ELSE result_and WHEN S="0010"
        ELSE "XXXX";
```

... etc...

Note that adder and subtractors are usually combined.

Answer (score 1):

Your code and idea has several faults:

1. A `case` statement can only be embedded in a process or sub routine.
2. You can not instanciate sub modules in a process.
3. Sub modules are not restricted to a single return value so you can not use a instance statement as an expressions on the right hand side like a function.

Please consult any VHDL textbook for the correct syntax.

Comment: VHDL got no modules, the word shows up exactly once in the standard and not in this context. Ditto for sub modules. The way to conditionally instantiate concurrent statements (including components) is through the use of generate statements, wherein in -2008 case generate statements are supported. Note that `S` is not a valid expression for one, signal values are not globally static (not available at elaboration time) IEEE Std 1076-2008, 11.8 Generate statements.